# Swift reading a json file

Tags: json, swift

I am having this error. Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: String, options: [Any])'
I am thinking it has to be a different type for the file but not sure.
I don't think doing bundle.main.url would be the correct way to do this. I had seen that in another question that suggested using url, but also not sure how it'd work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

This is code for writing into file in InfoViewController

```
let fileName: String?
    let file: FileHandle? = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: "fileName.json")


    if file != nil {
        // Set the data we want to write
        do{
            if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: fileName!, options: .init(rawValue: 0))
            {
                // Check if everything went well
                //print(NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: 1)!)
                let bookCover = (jsonData as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "bookCoverImage.image") as? [UIImage]
                let bookTitle = (jsonData as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "bookTitleLabel.text") as? [String]
                let author = (jsonData as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "authorLabel.text") as? [String]
                let year = (jsonData as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "bookYear.text") as? [String]
                let pages = (jsonData as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "numberOfPages") as? [String]
                let ratingStars = (jsonData as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "ratingStars.image") as? [UIImage]
                let reviews = (jsonData as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "totalReviews.text") as? [String]
                let description = (jsonData as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "descriptionLabel.text") as? [String]
                file?.write(jsonData)

                // Do something cool with the new JSON data
            }
        }
        catch {

        }
        // Write it to the file

        // Close the file
        file?.closeFile()
    }
```

This is the code where the error is occurring. In favoritesListController.

```
var path: String?
var favoritesList: String?
var bookCoversDisplay = [UIImage]()
var titlesDisplay = [String]()
var authorsDisplay = [String]()
var yearDisplay = [String]()
var pagesDisplay = [String]()
var starRatingDisplay = [UIImage]()
var reviewsDisplay = [String]()
var descriptionsDisplay = [String]()


var bookCovers: UIImage!
var titles: String = ""
var authors: String = ""
var year: String = ""
var pages: String = ""
var starRating: UIImage!
var reviews: String = ""
var descriptions: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "favoritesList", ofType: "json")
    do {
        favoritesList = try String(contentsOfFile: path!)
        let jsonResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: favoritesList, options: [])

        if let array = jsonResult as? [Any] {
            if let bookCover = array.first {
                bookCoversDisplay = bookCover
            } else if let title = array.second {
                titlesDisplay = title
            } else if let author = array.third {
                authorsDisplay = author
            } else if let year = array.fourth {
                yearDisplay = year
            } else if let pages = array.fifth {
                pagesDisplay = pages
            } else if let starRating = array.sixth {
                starRatingDisplay = starRating
            } else if let reviews = array.seventh {
                reviewsDisplay = reviews
            } else if let description = array.eighth {
                descriptionsDisplay = description
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should review the documentation for `JSONSerialization` to see the correct parameters for `jsonObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe can help you:

```
    do{
  let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "json")!))
   let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
        print(json)
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked but I'm not sure if I'm passing the values of the book correctly to the file and how would I read them as different arrays, like all titles and pages are together in different array.

Comment: I had did select by row and pushed that information back to InfoViewController

Comment: you can use `Decodable` converting [String:Any] to Book class